# In Qt, how to resize icons in a table?

Tags: qt, icons, qtablewidget

I put icons as items in a table:

```
QTableWidget *table = new QTableWidget(this);
QTableWidgetItem *item = new QTableWidgetItem;
item->setSizeHint(QSize(100, 100));
item->setIcon(QIcon(fileName));
table->setItem(0, 0, item);
```

However no matter the icons' size, they are shown extremely small in the table.
I do not care about the text.

How can I get them bigger?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to change the size of the icons in the `QTableWidget`.  You can do so using the `iconSize` property inherited from `QAbstractItemView`.  See [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#iconSize-prop).

```
QTableWidget *table = new QTableWidget(this);
table->setIconSize(QSize(100, 100));
QTableWidgetItem *item = new QTableWidgetItem;
item->setSizeHint(QSize(100, 100));
item->setIcon(QIcon(fileName));
table->setItem(0, 0, item);
```